# Detect if Cache Driver Supports Tags

Tags: php, caching, laravel, tags

Is there a clean way to determine if the current Cache engine supports `tags` in Laravel?  We're relying on an open source module/ServiceProvider that needs `tags` support, and I want to make sure our system is bullet proof such that switching the cache engine won't cause fatal errors.

Right now, if a user has a system configured with the file or database caching engines, the following code

```
Cache::tags([]);
```

throws an error

> `Illuminate\Cache\FileStore` does not have a method `tags`

If a user has a system configured with something like memcached or redis, the code works without issue.

Is there a way to cleanly detect if the currently configured cache engine supports tags?  The best I've been able to come up with is

```
$app = app();
$has_tags = method_exists($app['cache']->driver()->getStore(), 'tags');
```

but that's making a lot of assumptions w/r/t to there being a `cache` service configured, and that the cache service users a "driver", that the driver users a "store", and that the `tags` method isn't there fore another purpose.

I've also thought about wrapping the call to `Cache::get` in a try/catch, but then I'm relying on Laravel's "throw an exception for a PHP error" behavior not changing in a future version.

Is there an obvious solution I'm missing?

Comment: For reference: You can also get the store by calling Cache::getStore() directly, i.e. `method_exists(Cache::getStore(), 'tags')`

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone else arriving here, the correct answer would be:

```
if(Cache::getStore() instanceof \Illuminate\Cache\TaggableStore) {
    // We have a taggable cache.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a method for that since Laravel 8.10:

```php
if (Cache::supportsTags()) {
    // Do things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers work for the built-in cache drivers I've used [a tagged file cache driver](https://github.com/unikent/taggedFileCache) which has a store that unfortunately does not extend `TaggableStore`

The only way I could get this to work was by doing:

```
 if (method_exists(Cache::store($type)->getStore(), 'tags')) {
    // Supports tags
 }
```

Reason is (I'm guessing) that `TaggableStore` is an abstract class and not an interface so it kind of limits the options.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to generate a list of the stores that support tagging, use this:

```
$stores = collect(config('cache.stores'))
    ->keys()
    ->flatMap(function ($type) {
        return [
            $type => Cache::store($type)->getStore() instanceof Illuminate\Cache\TaggableStore,
        ];
    });
```

These are the answers for the default cache stores (on 5.2 installation, other versions seem the same):

- apc: true
- array: true
- database: false
- file: false
- memcached: true
- redis: true