# Laravel 5 cache tags on file drivers

Tags: laravel, caching, tags

Will laravel 5 support cache tags on file drivers ?

I am trying to you cache tags but i am getting following error

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Illuminate\Cache\FileStore' does not have a method 'tags'

I have tried in this way

```
Cache::tags('family')->put('wife','Umme Mufeez',10);
Cache::tags('family')->put('Kid','Mufeez', 10);
Cache::tags('family')->put('husband','Abu Mufeez', 10);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel does not support cache tags in the file driver.

It clearly states it in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache#cache-tags):

> **Note:** Cache tags are not supported when using the `file` or `database` cache drivers.

Comment: Mine is on Array and still the same

Comment: My answer on another question lists which stores support tagging and how to generate that list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730228/detect-if-cache-driver-supports-tags/41072587#41072587